# Attaching libraries to specific controllers

Tags: 8, javascript, charts

I want to include the google charts js library to a specific (or set of) controller(s).  In my library file, `gcharts.libraries.yml`, I have the following:

```
google_charts:
  remote: https://developers.google.com/chart
  version: current
  license:
    name: apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js: { type: external, minified: true }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Which, unless I copied something incorrectly, should be correct.

***Question 1***: is the `dependencies` tag allowed here?  The documentation isn't expressly clear on that.

---

My controller (`GoogleChartsController`) correctly instantiates and looks like:

```
<?php
array(
  '#theme' => 'custom_theme',
  '#attached' =>
    array(
      'library' =>
        array('company/google_charts')
    ),
  // For testing purposes
  '#cache' => array(
    'max_age' => 0,
  )
);
?>
```

However, when I look through the source I don't see the library that I told my controller has a dependency for.  My library never loads.

***Question 2***: Do I have *have* to use the `hook_page_attachement` or the `hook_preprocess_page` hooks?  If so, how do I limit it to use just my set of controllers I want (I don't need or want this loading on every page)?  Can I get the path, check to see that it is what I want and then add it conditionally, like so?  Or is there some other way?

---

My `custom-theme.html.twig` looks like:

```
<div id="testing-div">Are we here?</div>
<!-- inflate chart here -->
<div id="chart-div"></div>
```

The documentation isn't crystal clear as to when and where to include inline js.  From the google charts api, I'm to include something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  // issue google charts api call to inflate chart at "chart-div"
  // omitted rest for brevity
</script>
```

Now, my intuition is that I can actually abstract each of the charts I want into their own "library" and add the dependency, because of the way I designed things, this will be fairly trivial.  But I'm not certain if this is the best way to do it.  But I've read that you *can* dump inline js into twig files; but I'm not 100% certain this applies here...

***Question 3***: Is adding the js into twig best practices or is libraries the way to go?  Assuming libraries, can I include several libraries into one library file and just include the one(s) that I want/need?  So I would have one library for `customized_charts.libraries.yml` and in there there would be declarations for `pie_chart`, `bar_chart`, etc.  And then I would load `module/bar_chart` when I wanted to display bar charts, etc?

Comment: Please show the route definition and the full controller callback.

Answer (score 2):

You are not indenting parts of the yml file that you need to indent.

Look at this example from token.libraries.yml at /modules/contrib/token/token.libraries.yml:

```
jquery.treeTable:
  remote: 'http://plugins.jquery.com/treetable/'
  version: 3.2.0
  license:
    name: MIT
    url: https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable/blob/3.2.0/MIT-LICENSE.txt
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    js/jquery.treetable.js: {}
  css:
    component:
      css/jquery.treetable.css: {}
      css/token.treetable.theme.css: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Also, pay attention to colons, since they are part of YAML syntax.

use:

```
remote: 'remote: https://developers.google.com/chart'
```

not

```
remote: remote: https://developers.google.com/chart
```

Comment: I was going to say the same, but I ran it through an online YAML linter and it said it was okay.

Comment: That's because it's valid YAML, but it won't be parsed in the correct way, each row will be a separate array, instead of all being part of the same array.

Comment: ...smh, that is just an error in translation.  My actual `gcharts.libraries.yml` has the correct indentation.  I just mistyped the number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

To answer two of your questions:

> Question 2: Do I have have to use the hook_page_attachement or the
>   hook_preprocess_page hooks?

No, you can attach libraries to a controller.

> Question 3: Is adding the js into twig best practices or is libraries
>   the way to go?

It's not a good practice to add JS into a template. It should be added to whichever render array represents the data the script belongs to.

Comment: Yes, I discovered last night, that I was misinterpreting the documentation.  I didn't realized that it was `module_name.libraries.yml`.  I thought it was just `library_name.libraries.yml`.  I have it attaching to my render array in my controller just fine now.  As for #3: I have several different chart types, does it makes sense to just build a library for each of those and include them as needed?  That brings a whole host of other challenges, but it seems that it is the best Drupal compatible approach...

Comment: Yes, you'll want to build libraries for each of your chart types.